# React JSX array.map() cannot read data. undefined

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I got props array "tags"

Array "tags" is :
[image]

And I want render this array using JSX and array.map()

```
                        {/* [undefined, undefined, ... ] */} 
                        {tags.map((tag) => {   
                            console.log(tag.tag); // it's okay. printed well tag.tag
                            <p1>{tag.tag}</p1>    // it's not okay. tag.tag is undefined.  
                        })}                 
                        {/* it's okay */}          
                        <p1>{tags[0].tag}</p1>
```

What is problem..? T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your map is not returning anything. You need to return your JSX from map.
Rewrite the above code as below:

```
{tags.map((tag) => {   
    console.log(tag.tag); // it's okay. printed well tag.tag
    return (<p1>{tag.tag}</p1>)   
 })}
```